# How to implement automatic OAuth for official client and manual for third parties

Tags: node.js, oauth, passport.js

i'm building a web Api with node.js and a client to consume the service with Ember.js. This client is considered to be "The Official" as the service is intended to be consumed also by third parties (like twitter, facebook, g+, does).

My concern is the security of the API.

The approach i'm trying to accomplish is to implement oauth 2.0 with the oauth2orize module to give access to every registered client the user authorises. The problem with this is the user would have to authorise the official client too, like it was a third party client. I want the authorization to be transparent to the users login into the official client.

Is there a way to avoid the authorization or give it automatically to the official client for every registered user?

Is this the best approach?. My other idea is to use basic (user:password:cookies) authentication for the official client and leave the authorization part only for third parties. In that case, how would i know if a request is coming from a third party or the official client to use the proper authorization schema?

thanks in advance.

Comment: I am confused by the third-party references. But here is what I understand. You want user to be able to use their google/facebook/twitter accounts with ouath but also have to authorize them for your client ?

Comment: No, I'm making my own service with my own client. And I want other people to make their own clients to work with my service too. No twitter or Facebook involved, I was just saying that I wanted to make a service like theirs. My problem is that if use oauth to authorize clients, then the users would have to authorize my client too, wich is the official and should be preauthorized